# When setting exported = false, the app doesn't launch

Tags: android, security

My Android app went through the [Quixxi Vulnerability](https://quixxi.com/vulnerability-report/) scan and one of the High risk issues was:

```
Vulnerability : Using Activities/Improper Export of Android Application Activities
Severity : High

Export tag for following activities are not used properly:
com.domain.appname.activities.SplashActivity
```

In the manifest it looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I set `android:exported="false"` the app doesn't start anymore and Android Studio just shows `Client not ready yet..`.

How can I fix the vulnerability reported by Quixxi?

Comment: "the app doesn't start anymore": why? What's the error you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no vulnerability, and you cannot "fix" it in terms of somehow improving the security. A launcher activity is supposed to be launched by third-party launchers, and hence it needs to be exported.

Since you have an `<intent-filter>`, having `android:exported` is not necessary. It is possible that by removing this attribute, you will "fix" the problem from Quixxi's perspective.

You might reconsider using Quixxi, given this false positive report.

Comment: ostorlab also throwing same error. App not opening. When I set export:true for launcher activity. How can I fix that.

Comment: @Amsheer: I do not know what "ostorlab" is. I do not know what "App not opening" means. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you take your time and explain **in detail** what your problem is.

Comment: starting Android 12 if your app targets 12 exported attribute should be specified for all activity entries in manifest that have intent-filter

Comment: @CommonsWare as KingKongCoder mentioned setting exported attribute is necessary for all components. what should we do in this case? if I set exported to true, libraries like dexguard and sonar cube will show me vulnerability.

Comment: @SamanSattari "mentioned setting exported attribute is necessary for all components" -- that is not what his comment states. You need to explicitly set `android:exported` for all `<activity>` entries that have an `<intent-filter>`. "if I set exported to true, libraries like dexguard and sonar cube will show me vulnerability" -- then remove the `<intent-filter>`, if you do not need it. If you do need it, update those tools to newer versions that stop reporting false positives, or stop using those tools entirely.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need <intent-filter> (<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />) and because of that i set the exported to true. all these tools are saying that if we set exported true, we should apply some permissions to that component based on OWASP security issues

Comment: @SamanSattari: If you are expecting other apps to launch this activity, then your manifest settings are correct, and "all these tools" are simply wrong, or you are misinterpreting what they are telling you. If, on the other hand, you are *not* expecting other apps to launch this activity, then you should be able to remove the `<intent-filter>` and `android:exported` to make "all these tools" happier.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been fixed, thanks for raising the problem

More in general please bear in mind that Quixxi Vulnerability Test is based on the static analysis of the code. For this reason it is intrinsically subject - as every other vulnerability scanner on the market - to false positives that can be really assessed only with a dynamic analysis

So our vulnerability report is intended to be an app pre-screening on the way the code is written and on the best SW practices to guarantee security to you and your end users